# write number within a range in input text

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two text inputs which are linked by their v-model to a ref that is an object, I have two more refs: minimum(100) and maximum(1000) which I am looking for is to be able to write in these inputs between the range of minimum and maximum, but if the value that I write is less than the minimum, it will automatically show the minimum value (100), if it is greater than the maximum, it will show the maximum.

```
<input type="text" v-model="number.one" class="one" @input="validate"/> 
<input type="text" v-model="number.two" class="two" @input="validate"/>

const min = ref(100)
const max = ref(1000)

const numbers = ref({
   one: 100,
   two: 100
}) 

const validate = () => {
    if(e.target.className === 'one'){
      if(numbers.value.one <= min.value){
         numbers.value.one = min.value
      }else if(numbers.value.one > max.value){
         numbers.value.one = max.value
      }
    }
}
```

I do this, but from here it no longer lets me write anything in the input, I think I know it's because numbers.value.one is now equal to the minimum so I can't modify it anymore, but how can I change the amounts?

Answer (score 1):

Checking min & max values for inputs can be easily achieved by tuning their HTML props. There is no need for extra validation.

```html
<template>
  <input type="number" v-model="numbers.two" :max="max"/>
  <input type="number" v-model="numbers.one" :min="min"/>
</template>

<script setup lang="js">

import { reactive, ref } from 'vue';

const min = ref(100);
const max = ref(1000);

const numbers = reactive({
  one: 100,
  two: 100,
});
</script>
```

However, if you persist in checking every change's values, you need to validate ranges on input or change events.

```html
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="numbers.one" class="one" @input="validateMax"/>
  <input type="text" v-model="numbers.two" class="two" @change="validateMin"/>
  <!--  <input type="text" v-model="numbers.two" class="two" @input="validateMin"/>-->
</template>

<script setup lang="js">

import { reactive, ref } from 'vue';

const min = ref(100);
const max = ref(1000);

const numbers = reactive({
  one: 100,
  two: 100,
});

function validateMax() {
  numbers.one = Math.min(Number(numbers.one), max.value);
}

function validateMin() {
  numbers.two = Math.max(Number(numbers.two) || 0, min.value);
}

</script>
```

Here, on every change, new values are validated against min and max values, and the model gets updated.

There are some edge cases that must be addressed. Checking the min value on every input event breaks the user interface. As your min value is 100, when a number like 250 is going to be entered, at the very first step, the validation event is triggered by 2 and the value will be converted to 100. So, in practice, you cannot use the `input` event here. The `change` event must be used.

**Note 1** It is a good practice to use `v-model.number` for numeric bindings.

**Note 2** It also is a good practice to use `type="number"` for numeric inputs.

Comment: What I was looking for was that in the same input only be able to write in the min-max range, in the first input only write values between 100 and 1000, if I write 50 it will show 100, if I write 1200 it will show 1000, I use input text because I apply quantity format to entered values

Comment: To achieve that, you can set both min and max props on the same input. It will take care of your range. `<input type="number" v-model="numberRange" :min="min" :max="max"/>`

Comment: Yes, but if I change to number I can't apply the format to the amounts, which I do using this: replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3}) +(?!\d))/g, ","), that's why I don't use the input number